# Express router delete and Firebase Cloud Function gives TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, express-router

I have a Firebase Cloud function with firebase.json config as:

```
{
    "hosting":
    {
        "public": "public",
        "ignore": [
            "firebase.json",
            "**/.*",
            "**/node_modules/**"
        ],
        "rewrites": [
        {
            "source": "**",
            "function": "api"
        },
        {
            "source": "/*",
            "function": "api"
        }]
    }
}
```

I have been inspired by: [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@alfianlosari/serverless-node-js-rest-api-with-google-cloud-function-firestore-d7b422f58511) and [this turorial](https://itnext.io/building-a-serverless-restful-api-with-cloud-functions-firestore-and-express-f917a305d4e6)

router.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const cors = require('cors')
const firebaseHandler = require('../db/firebaseHandler')
router.use(cors())

router.delete('/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const id = req.params.id;
        if (!id) throw new Error('id is blank');
        await firebaseHandler.delete('worklogs', id);
        res.json({
            id
        });
    } catch(e) {
        next(e);
    }
});
module.exports = router;
```

firebaseHandler.js

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
const conf = require('../../../conf.json')

const config = {
    apiKey: conf.firebaseConfig.apiKey,
    authDomain: conf.firebaseConfig.authDomain,
    databaseURL: conf.firebaseConfig.databaseURL,
    projectId: conf.firebaseConfig.projectId,
    schemaPath: conf.schemaPath
};

firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);

const db = firebaseApp.firestore();

exports.delete = async (type, id) => {
    await database.collection(type).doc(id).delete(); 
}
```

I'm getting the error when running this in the url: http://localhost:5000/mycloudfunctionhere/api/documentidhere/

Here is the stack trace of the error:

```
projectpath\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635
    return fn.apply(this, arguments);

TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
      at Immediate.<anonymous> (projectpath\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:15)
      at runCallback (timers.js:706:11)
      at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
      at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
```

Nothing specific and I have tried out multiple examples but I keep getting this error..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please tell where is database object defined like that admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault()
});
const db = admin.firestore();

Comment: Which specific line in your code is causing this error? To help we will need more than just the message. Take a look at the error's stack trace and find which line comes from one of your files.

Comment: I have updated my question with firebase configuration in firebaseHandler.js @MaheshBhatnagar

Comment: @samthecodingman - It doesn't say witch line it comes from - other than
/myprojectpath/node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635

      return fn.apply(this, arguments);

     >  TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
>      at Immediate.<anonymous> (myprojectpath\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:15)
>      at runCallback (timers.js:706:11)
>      at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
>      at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)

Comment: Please use this code  await db.collection(''worklogs'').doc(id).delete();

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar - I've tried: await firebaseHandler.delete(id); and await db.collection("worklogs").doc(id).delete();. Still getting the error :-/

Comment: can you share your full code if no problem you

Comment: It is like the router.delete() method does not work. I've even tried to just console.log("hello") on my router.delete(/:id, () => ) method. Still getting the error. @MaheshBhatnagar - There is no more code than this I have posted here now

Comment: ok sir, i am checking that issue, Please tell me, are you sure that you got id value in function

Comment: And tried the delete method from here: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html . And trying http://localhost:5000/cloudfunction/api/user . Same error..

Comment: Can you post the code where you attach the router to the Cloud Function?

Comment: Is that the complete `router.js` file? Aren't you missing `module.exports = router` at the bottom of the file?

Comment: @samthecodingman - Sorry, I do have that line in my code (added it to my question now)

Comment: Please use this query router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("hello");
}); and comment of delete function & router of

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar: That gives me the same error. But it is working perfectly fine with router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => { console.log("hello"); });

Comment: Please share full code

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the lack of knowledge that you cannot make a delete request in a browser url. It worked as soon as I made a curl -x DELETE http://localhost:5000/mycloudfunctionhere/api/documentidhere/

Thank you for your answers everyone!